# Firebase signup/login via web3

Tags: javascript, jquery, firebase, web3js, metamask

Instead of using the normal firebase authentication methods I want to use web3 (specifically metamask) to provide signup/login without the need of email and passwords. The problem is, how do I handle signups?

One way I thought of doing it would be to use the users wallet address as the email and just add my domain as the @ part for example: 0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000@example.com but then the problem is how do I add a password for firebase to use?

Is there anyway to authenticate using metamask?

Answer (score 0):

I wish I had seen this question earlier, We have developed a mechanism just for this requires a server that runs the `firebase-admin` that mints a custom token and pass it to the client and signs in with `signInWithCustomToken`.

The code is here https://github.com/novum-insights/sveltekit-unlock-firebase.

This is a boilerplate that uses sveltekit and paywalls the user with unlock-protocol.

Answer (score 0):

You could get the account from MetaMask with web3.js.

Then create a Firebase user like you said with `account + "@example.com"` and always the same password like `123456`.

Then sign in with `account + "@example.com"` and password `123456`.

Problem is when attacker knows or guesses another users wallet account :)

```
// Get wallet account with web3.js

<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/web3@latest/dist/web3.min.js"></script>

let account = null;

getWalletAccount();
async function getWalletAccount() {
    if (window.ethereum) {
        window.web3 = new Web3(window.ethereum);
        try {
            const accounts = await ethereum.request({ method: "eth_requestAccounts" });
            account = accounts[0];
            console.log("User's account is: " + account);
        } catch (e) {
            console.log("Error in eth_requestAccounts", e);
        }
    }
}

// Create user with Firebase

import { signInWithEmailAndPassword, createUserWithEmailAndPassword } from "https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/10.7.1/firebase-auth.js";

let email = account + "@example.com";
let password = "123456";

createUser();
function createUser() {
    createUserWithEmailAndPassword(auth, email, password).then(cred => {
        console.log(cred);
    }).catch((error) => {
        const errorCode = error.code;
        const errorMessage = error.message;
        // ..
    });
}

// Sign in user with email address (ethereum account + "@example.com") and password

startAuthenticationWithEmailAndPassword();
function startAuthenticationWithEmailAndPassword() {
    signInWithEmailAndPassword(auth, email, password)
        .then((userCredential) => {
            // Signed in 
            const user = userCredential.user;
            // ...
            console.log("Signed in with email and password");
            console.log("User has uid: " + user.uid);
        })
        .catch((error) => {
            const errorCode = error.code;
            const errorMessage = error.message;
        });
}
```